# Changing material-ui theme on the fly --> Doesn't affect children

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm working on a react/redux-application where I'm using material-ui.

I am setting the theme in my **CoreLayout-component** (my top layer component) using context (in accordance to the documentation). This works as expected on initial load.

I want to be able to switch themes during runtime. When I select a new theme, my redux store gets updated and therefore triggers my components to update. The problem is that the children of my CoreLayout-component doesn't get affected - the first time! If I repeatedly change my theme (using a select-list that sends out a redux-action onChange) the children are updated. If a child component is located 2 layers down in my project hierarchy, it is updated after 2 action calls - so there is some issue with how the context is passed down.

**My CoreLayout.js component**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ThemeManager from 'material-ui/lib/styles/theme-manager';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    uiStatus: state.uiStatus
});

export class CoreLayout extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
        return {
            muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(this.props.uiStatus.get("applicationTheme").toJS())
        };
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className='page-container'>
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

CoreLayout.propTypes = {
   children: PropTypes.element
};

CoreLayout.childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoreLayout);
```

**One of my child components (LeftNavigation.js)**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    uiStatus: state.uiStatus
});

export class LeftNavigation extends React.Component {
    render () {

        return (
            <div className="left-pane-navigation">
                <List subheader="My Subheader" >
                    <ListItem primaryText="Search" />
                    <ListItem primaryText="Performance Load" />
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

LeftNavigation.contextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LeftNavigation);
```

I can access the theme located in context by this.context.muiTheme.
I can get the component to update the theme by using another instance of getChildContext() inside each child component, but I will have such a large number of components that I would very much like to avoid having to do that.

My CoreLayout component's getChildContext-method is called when I change theme and all my child components gets re-rendered as expected.

Any ideas?

Update: It works as expected on mobile devices (at least iOS)

Answer (score 0):

You can use muiThemeProvider to avoid having to add getChildContext to any child component, the provider does this for you.

```
...

import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

const App = () => (
 <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
 </MuiThemeProvider>
)

...
```

More info in [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage).

Comment: Yea, I did that at first, but got tired of having to add that to every component I added.

The context approached worked itself out along with wrapping my "RootView" in the <MuiThemeProvider />